# How exactly works Spring Security configuration in this Spring Boot project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I am not so into **Spring Security**. I am working on a **Spring Boot** project (implementing some REST web sercices) where someone else have implemented Spring Security to perform authentication. It seems works fine but I have some doubts about how it exactly works (the architecture).

So basically I have the following classes:

1) **User** that is my **model class** representing a user:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user",
        uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"email","username"})
})
public class User  {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;


    //@Pattern(regexp="\\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}\\b",flags = Pattern.Flag.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
    @Column(name="email", unique=true,nullable=false)
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="registration_date",nullable=false)
    private Date registration_date;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name="username",nullable = false,unique=true)
    private String username;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name="password",nullable = false)
    private String password;


    @Column(name="enabled", nullable = false)
    private boolean enabled;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_user_roles", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "id_user", updatable = true) },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_roles",
                    updatable = true)},
            uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"id_user","id_roles"})}
    )
    @Cascade({CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REFRESH,CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
    private List<UserRole> userRoles;

    // CONSTRUCTOR, GETTER AND SETTER METHODS
}
```

It is an hibernate class that provide the join with the **user_user_roles** database table containing the list of user rool associated to the specific user (I think the **ROLE_ADMIN**, **ROLE_USER**, etcetc)

2) Then I have **CustomUserDetails** class that extends **User** and implements Spring Security **UserDetails** interface.

So it means that will contain all the information related to a specific user (among which the role associated to this user) and implement all the methods declared in the **UserDetails** interface.

```
public class CustomUserDetails extends User implements UserDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public CustomUserDetails(User user){
        super(user);
    }


    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
        for(UserRole role : this.getUserRoles() ){
            GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName());
            authorities.add(grantedAuthority);
        }

        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return super.getUsername();
    }

}
```

It seems to me that this class represent the bridge between Spring application and Spring Security (something like that carry the roles information related to a specific user, is it?).

In this class the information related to the list of roles of an user is contained into a collection of generic object that extends **GrantedAuthority**.

I think that the **GrantedAuthority** objects represents the roles of a user (infact are builded by **role.getName()** that is the string representing a role of the current user). Is it this reasoning correct?

Basically the prvious implementation only return the collection of **GrantedAuthority** related to a specific user, is it?

3) The **CustomUserDetailsService** class implementing Spring Security **UserDetailsService** interface:

```
@Transactional
@Service("customUserDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{
    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDao;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userDao.findByUsername(username);
        if(user == null){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user present with username: "+username);
        }else{
            return new CustomUserDetails(user);
        }
    }

}
```

Basically this is a service that only implements the **loadUserByUsername(String username))** method that do:

- First retrieve the information related the user (a **User** object) including the list of his roles (**List userRoles**).
- Then use this **User** object to build the previous **CustomUserDetails** used to retrieve the collection of the **GrantedAuthority** related to the user.

Is all these reasoning correct?

Then I also have this **WebSecurityConfig** that I think represent the **Spring Security** configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = CustomUserDetailsService.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired 
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    }
}
```

This is pretty obsucre for me. What exactly does?

From what I have understand it is enabling the REST web services security by ** @EnableWebSecurity**.

But why does the autowire of the **UserDetailsService** bean?

And what exactly foes this empty **configure()** method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct.

Spring-security requires you to create a service which implements *UserDetailsService*. It expects service to have *loadUserByUsername* method which returns user object (which needs to implement Spring's *User* class). This instance of user is used to get authorities so that you can restrict access to certain urls. i.e. you can map url access to users with specific authorities.

In terms of the empty method configure(), it is used to for authentication and authorisation of the urls (mentioned above) and few more things. In fact, in terms of security, this is most flexible & powerful method available.

My project's config method looks like this:

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/","/static/**").permitAll()
                    .mvcMatchers("/admin").access("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')")
                    .mvcMatchers("/employees").access("hasAuthority('ROLE_STAFF')")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                .httpBasic()
                    .and()
                  .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                    .and()
                    .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                    .and()
                .headers().contentSecurityPolicy("default-src 'self' " +
                                                 "https://ajax.googleapis.com " +
                                                 "https://cdnjs.cloudfare.com " +
                                                 "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' ");


    }
```

The above example

- Ensures all requests are authenticated and authorized.
- Permits free access to static resources
- Ensures url /admin is accessible only by users with role ADMIN
- Setup basic login prompt for authentication
- Sets logout url
- Sets up cookie based CSRF token system
- Sets content security policy

To understand more about all spring-security features, I highly recommend these resources.

- [excellent video presentations](https://www.infoq.com/author/Rob-Winch) from Rob Winch (lead on Spring Security project)
- [Site with good examples](http://websystique.com/spring-security/spring-security-4-password-encoder-bcrypt-example-with-hibernate/)
- [Sample code repo](https://github.com/rwinch/spring-security-4.1-and-beyond/tree/master/rest)